# Calculating the integral periodic functions times the heaviside function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, dirac-delta

> $$\int_0^{t'}sin \left(2t-\frac{\pi}{4} \right)H(t)dt'$$

I tried integrating by parts:

$$dg = sin\left(2t-\frac{\pi}{4} \right) \rightarrow g = -\frac12cos\left(2t-\frac{\pi}{4} \right) $$

$$ f = H(t) \rightarrow df = \delta(t)$$

Plugging everything in:

$$ -H(t)\left(\frac12cos\left(2t-\frac{\pi}{4} \right)\right)|^{t'}_{0}+\int_0^{t'} \delta(t)\frac12cos\left(2t-\frac{\pi}{4} \right) dt'$$

What is the right most integral give me? It seems as though I can't apply any of the properties of the delta function to this integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Heaviside function is equal to 1 in the entire interior of the integral's domain (assuming $t'>0$).  So 
$$\int_0^{t'}sin \left(2t-\frac{\pi}{4} \right)H(t)dt'=\int_0^{t'}sin \left(2t-\frac{\pi}{4} \right)dt'$$

Comment: thanks for the reply. Wolframalpha gives me $ \frac{1}{4}H(t)(\sqrt{2}-2sin(2t+\frac{\pi}{4}))$. 

Is there a reason why it's so different than your integral?

Comment: @RonaldB Paul assumes $t'>0$ explicitly, in which case $H(t')=1$. If $t'<0$, then the Heaviside function is instead zero over the entire range and therefore the integral vanishes; correspondingly, $H(t')=0$ in that case and the WA result vanishes as well. So the two agree for all $t'$.